# Function to Generate SKUS when product is updated or saved

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to create a function to take an ACF field with 3 different color variation prefixes for a product and generate variation SKUS based on product attributes. I want the function to generate the SKUS then assign, update and save the SKUS to the corresponding variations.

I have been trying to figure out why this doesn't generate and update the WooCommerce variations SKUS.

I have another function that is taking my ACF fields then generating a product title updating and replacing the title and slug. I have function that is taking ACF fields from the product and generating a product description and short description short codes that display on the from end.

The only thing I am doing differently in this function is trying to import attributes to generate the SKUS

This is what I have so far

```
// *START -- Generate Product Variation SKUS

// Function to auto generate SKU
function generate_sku($variation_id) {
    // Get product variation
    $product = wc_get_product($variation_id);

    // Set prefix based on color attribute
    $prefix = get_field('sku_prefixes_space_gray', $variation_id);
    if (empty($prefix)) {
        $prefix = get_field('sku_prefixes_silver', $variation_id);
    }
    if (empty($prefix)) {
        $prefix = get_field('sku_prefixes_gold', $variation_id);
    }

    // Only generate the SKU if a valid prefix is present
    if (!empty($prefix)) {
        // Get and format the values of specific attributes
        $ram_size = $product->get_attribute('pa_memory');
        $ram_size = str_replace('GB RAM', 'M', $ram_size); // format RAM size

        $drive_size = $product->get_attribute('pa_storage');
        // Format drive size
        $drive_sizes = array(
            '1TB SSD' => '1024S',
            '2TB SSD' => '2048S',
        '4TB SSD' => '4096S',
        '8TB SSD' => '8192S'
        );
        $drive_size = isset($drive_sizes[$drive_size]) ? $drive_sizes[$drive_size] : str_replace('GB SSD', 'S', $drive_size);

        $condition = $product->get_attribute('pa_condition');
        // Format condition
        $conditions = array(
            'Mint' => 'CR',
            'Grade A' => 'CRG',
            'Grade B' => 'EX',
            'Grade C' => 'AV'
        );
        $condition = isset($conditions[$condition]) ? $conditions[$condition] : $condition;

        // Generate the SKU
        $new_sku = $prefix . '_' . $ram_size . $drive_size . '_' . $condition;
        $product->set_sku($new_sku);
    
        $product->save();
    }
}

// Hook for WooCommerce manual save
add_action('woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'generate_sku', 10, 2);


// *END -- Generate Product Variation SKUS
```

Comment: You are trying to update $product while you should update variation - check the source here to have better understanding - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3377c60c5e5602a4c82b6ef43b7b48b9c895f9ad/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php

Comment: Thanks for the link. This helped me get what I needed